# How to change "mute" the function of \ll in latex-suite?

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I am trying to figure out where the compile mapping (`<leader>ll`) is defined in latex-suite and then mute that function. I want `<leader>ll` to do something else. But after I define the new mapping in `.vimrc`, I noticed that it will be overwritten by Latex-Suite when I edit a `.tex` file.

Could anybody help me to fix the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That mapping is most likely defined by your plugin's ftplugin. You can see where it is defined by executing this command in a `tex` buffer:

```
:verbose map <leader>ll
```

If the mapping is defined in an ftplugin, you can override it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>ll dosomething
```